# awk/perl print palindrome if not between brackets

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a file with a bunch of strings, one on each line. I want to find and print a string only if it contains a palindrome and that palindrome is not between brackets. Examples:

```
abba[cdef]gh    # print
abcd[effe]gh    # do not print
```

I currently have a one-liner that prints a line if the string is a palindrome

```
awk 'BEGIN { system("perl -lne \"print if length == 4 && reverse eq \\$_\" " ARGV[1]) }' words.txt
```

modified from [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/11-awk/dd32789e3597fa82.htm).

I'm thinking of using `sed` to remove everything between the brackets, then evaluate the remaining for palindromes.

Any other ideas on how to accomplish this in one line?

Comment: Can't you just use negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) e.g. `perl -ne 'print if /(?<!\[)(.)(.)$2$1(?!\])/'` ?

Comment: how long does the palindrome have to be? `(nothing)` would be a simplistic one; `a` would be a simple one, `aa` another...

Comment: Just a question: why does the solution have to fit in one line?

Comment: The palindrome can be of any length. In the example I used four. It does not necessarily need to fit in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all¹ the palindromes of 3 or more characters not inside `[...]`:

```
$ echo 'cac[ada]abacab' | perl -nle '
    while (/\[.*?\]|(?=(([^][])(?1)\2|[^][]?))./g) {
      print $1 if length $1 >= 3
    }'
cac
aba
bacab
aca
```

(note that it assumes single-byte characters, add `-Mopen=locale` for the locale definition of characters).

The core of the palindrome matching is a recursive regular expression. A palindrome is matched as either the empty string or a single character or a pair of matching characters with another palindrome in between. That would be `((.)(?1)\2|.?)`, where `(?1)` does the recursive part (matches what's inside the first part of `()`, except that here we replace `.` with `[^][]` (any character other than `]` and `[`).

When matching *all* occurrences with `/.../g`, perl searches for the next occurrence after the end of the first one, so if we had `\[.*?\]|(([^][])(?1)\2|[^][]?)`, we would not find `bacab` in `abacab` because it would first find `aba`, and then resume searching after that `aba`. So here instead, we match `(?=(palindrome)).` which matches a single character (`.`) provided it's at the start of a *palindrome* which is then captured in `$1`. That means we resume searching after that single character.

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, it finds the longest (of 3 characters or more) palindromes at every position in the string, skipping the `[...]`s, so it may not find *all* the occurrences. For instance in `ababa`, it would find `ababa` in first position, `bab` in third position, `aba` in second position, but not `aba` in first position.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

How about a one-liner? Use the bracketed word as the field separator:

```
perl -F'\[.*?\]' -le 'for $word (@F) {if ($word eq reverse $word) {print; break}}' file
```

A couple of edge cases not considered here:

- It does not look at string length
- It does not look to find a palindrome *within* the word: the whole word must be a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

While `[...]` could be filtered out in advance it may be more sensible to use a [lex-like scanner](https://perldoc.pl/perlop) to walk the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
LINE: while (readline) {    # for each line (files or stdin)
    LEX: {
        # skip any [] or [...] bits
        redo LEX if m{ \G \[ [^\]]* \] }cgx;
        # two or more not-[ not-vertical-whitespace (\r, \n) chars
        if (m{ \G ([^\[\v]{2,}) }cgx) {
            # palindrome? print the whole line
            if ( $1 eq reverse $1 ) {
                print;
                next LINE;
            }
            # may be more to come...
            redo LEX;
        }
        # advance the lexer a single character
        redo LEX if m{ \G . }cgx;
        # oh it's the end of the line as we know it
    }
}
```

Which with an expanded test case for various edge conditions:

```
% < input
abba[cdef]gh    # print
abcd[effe]gh    # do not print
[effe]f00f
asdf[]prinirp
a[]b[]edgegde
% perl palin < input
abba[cdef]gh    # print
[effe]f00f
asdf[]prinirp
a[]b[]edgegde
%
```

This could easily be adapted to ignore trailing comments or other such input.